# How to focus one textinput per time in react-native?

Tags: react-native, onfocus

I have 3 different textinput, **textinput1**, **textinput2** and **textinput 3**.

I want that when i click on **textinput1** that his bordercolor be blue, i did that and works.

What i want now is, when i click on **textinput2** to **textinput1** be back to his orignal color and the **textinput2** be blue now.

Example on the photo.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IH14D.png)

This is my code:

```
state = { isFocused: true };

 onFocusChange = () => {
this.setState({ isFocused: false });
}

render() {

return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.headline}>Website ou App</Text>

    //TEXTINPUT1

    <TextInput
      onFocus={this.onFocusChange}
      style={(this.state.isFocused) ? {marginTop: 5, height: 40, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: 'gray'} :  {marginTop: 5, height: 40, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: '#00b7eb'}}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ site: text })}
      value={this.state.site}

    //TEXTINPUT2

    <Text style={styles.headline}>Utilizador/Email</Text>
    <TextInput
      style={{ marginTop: 5, height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ local: text })}
      value={this.state.local}

    />
```

Some idea how i can do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Sharing my same answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63045438/12817213).

Set up your text inputs and their styles in a component. Then use state in the component to control your styles.

```
const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

<TextInput
    style={focus ? styles.inputOnFocus : styles.inputOnBlur}
    onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
    onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
/>
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputOnFocus: { borderColor: '#C0C0C0' },
    inputOnBlur: { borderColor: '#4b6cd5' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to track the name of the focused TextInput. You'll need to make sure to use the updater version of `setState` in the `blur` event to avoid race conditions between the `onBlur` and `onFocus` methods of the two inputs:

```
 state = { focusedInput: null };

 onFocusChange = (inputName) => {
   this.setState({focusedInput: inputName});
 }
 onBlurChange = (inputName) => {
   this.setState(state => {
     if (state.focusedInput === inputName) {
       return {focusedInput: null};
     }
     // no change if some other input already has focus
     return null;
   }
 }

render() {

return (

  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.headline}>Website ou App</Text>

    //TEXTINPUT1

    <TextInput
      onFocus={() => this.onFocusChange("input1")}
      onBlur={() => this.onBlurChange("input1")}
      style={(this.state.focusedInput === "input1") ? {marginTop: 5, height: 40, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: 'gray'} :  {marginTop: 5, height: 40, borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 5, borderColor: '#00b7eb'}}
      onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ site: text })}
      value={this.state.site} />
```

Repeat for other inputs with a name different than "input1".

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is just to create your own custom component to handle the border line. I have created a expo snack for you to see a workaround (other than the mentioned before). https://snack.expo.io/@ianvasco/e8efb0.

Anyway here is the code.

```
//somefile.js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default App = () => {
  const [isInputFocused, setInputFocused] = useState({input1: false, input2: false})
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
    <TextInput
      onFocus={() => setInputFocused((prev) => ({...prev, input1: true}))}
      onBlur={() => setInputFocused((prev) => ({...prev, input1: false}))}
      style={isInputFocused.input1 ? styles.input : styles.inputFocused }
      onChangeText={() => {}}/>

    <TextInput
      style={isInputFocused.input2 ? styles.input : styles.inputFocused }
      onChangeText={() => {}}
      onFocus={() => setInputFocused((prev) => ({...prev, input2: true}))}
      onBlur={() => setInputFocused((prev) => ({...prev, input2: false}))}
    />
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  inputFocused: {
    marginTop: 5,
    height: 40, 
    borderWidth: 2, 
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: 'grey'
  },
  input: {
    marginTop: 5,
    height: 40, 
    borderWidth: 2, 
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderColor: '#00b7eb'
  }
});
```

Also, I just added React Hooks. I encourage you to use them, since the code get simplified a lot. [Here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) is more about Hooks

Answer (score 0):

**Create Custom TextInput component which will set "borderColor" to "black" or "blue" in component with help of "onFocus" and "onBlur"  events. In this way you can use multiple TextInputs without any conditions in parent**

**Sample Code**

```
import React from "react";
import { SafeAreaView, TextInput, Text } from "react-native";

class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  state = { hasFocus: false };

  _onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: true });
  };

  _onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({ hasFocus: false });
  };

  render() {
    const borderColor = this.state.hasFocus ? "blue" : "black";
    return (
      <TextInput
        style={{ padding: 16, borderColor: borderColor, borderWidth: 1 }}
        onFocus={this._onFocus}
        onBlur={this._onBlur}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 16, textAlign: "center" }}>Website App</Text>
        <CustomTextInput />
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 16, textAlign: "center" }}>Email</Text>
        <CustomTextInput />
        <Text style={{ marginTop: 16, textAlign: "center" }}>Password</Text>
        <CustomTextInput />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}
```

**App Preview**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**We can control the multiple text input by using Switch case and method **

```js
  _onFocusTo=(data)=>{
    const {
      overdueAmount,
      bounceCharges,
      penalInterest,
      overdueCharges,
      collectionPickupCharge,
      ebcCharges,
      foreClosureAmount,
      amount,
    } = this.state;
    console.log("focus");
    switch(data) {
      case 1:{
        if(amount === "0"){
          this.setState({amount:""})
        }

      }break;
      case 2:{
        if(bounceCharges === "0"){
          this.setState({bounceCharges:""})
        }
      }break;
      case 3:{
        if(penalInterest === "0"){
          this.setState({penalInterest:""})
        }
      }break;
      case 4:{
        if(foreClosureAmount === "0"){
          this.setState({foreClosureAmount:""})
        }
      }break;
      case 5:{
        if(ebcCharges === "0"){
          this.setState({ebcCharges:""})
        }
      }break;
      case 6:{
        if(collectionPickupCharge === "0"){
          this.setState({collectionPickupCharge:""})
        }
      }break;

    }
    
}


/In Textinput make function and pass it to onFocus

<TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                style={styles.textInput1}
                placeholder={""}
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.labelTextColor1}
                keyboardType={"numeric"}
                onFocus={() => this._onFocusTo(1)}
                onBlur={this.addTotal}
                onChangeText={(amount) => this.setAmountDes(amount)}
                value={this.state.amount}
              />
<TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                style={styles.textInput1}
                placeholder={""}
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.labelTextColor1}
                onFocus={() => this._onFocusTo(2)}
                onBlur={this.addTotal}
                keyboardType={"numeric"}
                onChangeText={(bounce) => this.setBounce(bounce)}
                value={this.state.bounceCharges}
              />
<TextInput
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                style={styles.textInput1}
                placeholder={this.state.penalInterest}
                placeholderTextColor={Colors.labelTextColor1}
                onFocus={() => this._onFocusTo(3)}
                onBlur={this.addTotal}
                keyboardType={"numeric"}
                onChangeText={(penal) => this.setPenal(penal)}
                value={this.state.penalInterest}
              />
....continues
```

Comment: The switch case will help you to control the text input on focus