# Change style when TextInput onFocus and onBlur.React-Native

Tags: react-native, textinput

I have 40 TextInput in 5 page and need to change input text color onfocus:'white' and onBlur:'gray'
I know how make it for single input.But I need for multiple input

```
<TextInput 
  clearTextOnFocus={true}
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  style={[this.state.isFocused?styles.inputOnFocus:styles.input]}
  onChangeText={v=>handleInput('value',v)}
  value={this.state.value}
  onFocus={()=>this.setState({isFocused:true})}
  onBlur={()=>this.setState({isFocused:false})}

/>
```

Comment: Can you explain what behavior do you want and what is happening with the current code?
As i read this it should work just fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply give each one of the Inputs an ID and use that one to know which ID is focused:

```
<TextInput 
  clearTextOnFocus={true}
  keyboardType="number-pad"
  style={[this.state.FocusedItem === "TextInput1"? styles.inputOnFocus : styles.input]}
  onChangeText={v=>handleInput('value',v)}
  value={this.state.value}
  onFocus={()=>this.setState({FocusedItem: "TextInput1"})}
  onBlur={()=>this.setState({FocusedItem: ""})}
/>
```

In a `.map()` function it could be like:

```
arr.map( (item, index) => { 
   let ID = "TextInput"+index
   return (
       <TextInput 
          clearTextOnFocus={true}
          keyboardType="number-pad"
          style={[this.state.FocusedItem === ID? styles.inputOnFocus : styles.input]}
          onChangeText={v=>handleInput('value',v)}
          value={this.state.value}
          onFocus={()=>this.setState({FocusedItem: ID})}
          onBlur={()=>this.setState({FocusedItem: ""})}
       />
   ) 
})
```

This is just for focus purpose. If the code stays like this, all inputs will have the same value

Answer (score 6):

Set up your text inputs and their styles in a component. Then use state in the component to control your styles.

```
const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

<TextInput
    style={focus ? styles.inputOnFocus : styles.inputOnBlur}
    onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
    onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
/>
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    inputOnFocus: { borderColor: '#C0C0C0' },
    inputOnBlur: { borderColor: '#4b6cd5' }
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer it is clean and reusable. Well done @Austin-Poulson

Answer (score 0):

***After a 1/2 day search i got solution 100% working -  class component***

code start below

this.state={isFocused : false}

onFocusChange = () => {
this.setState({
isFocused: true,
});
console.log("Hello i am focused");
};

```
    onfocus={this.onFocusChange}
```